# vb.net working out how many days left

Tags: vb.net, date

This is going to be very simple question (I hope) and I'm coming here from a point of laziness.

How do I find out the number days left between two dates? i.e days left between current date and 12/02/2015? Do I need to format the date to something different from "DD/MM/YYYY" and if so how?

Comment: Dim days = (New DateTime(2015, 12, 2) - DateTime.Now).Days

Comment: "I'm coming here from a point of laziness". Are users finally admiting they don't care for searching and just want to ask for someone else to solve their problem? And also... is that good or bad?

Comment: Here's my lazy answer: _____________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim firstDate,secondDate As Date
Dim days as Integer
firstDate=CDate("12/02/2015")
secondDate=CDate("12/03/2017")
Dim numberOfDays As Integer=(secondDate-firstDate).TotalDays
```

Comment: I don't think that `TimeSpan` has a `ToDays` method.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy.  You just need to use the `TotalDays` property of the `TimeSpan` struct.  You don't need `CDate` or `DateDiff`.  Example:

```
Dim firstDate as New Date(2015, 12, 2)
Dim secondDate as New Date(2017, 12, 3)
Dim numberofDays as Double = (secondDate - firstDate).TotalDays
```

Comment: `+1` although even the weak answers are more than the question deserves

Answer (score 0):

use the `CDate` and `Datediff` functions:

```
Dim firstDate,secondDate As Date
Dim days as Integer
firstDate=CDate("12/02/2015")
secondDate=CDate("12/03/2017")
days=DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, firstDate, secondDate)
```

for changing the `format` of the date when converting from `String` to `Date` take a look at here[Custom Date and Time Format String in C# and VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx):

Comment: Dates do not have a format, and they cannot be formatted. Using `Format` on a string has no impact on the resulting Date.

Comment: There is no need to use `CDate` at all.  `DateTime` has a constructor that takes in integers for year/month/day.  I'm also not the biggest fan of `DateDiff` and the other stuff in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Comment: agreed.  VB also makes it easy to use a literal: `myDt = #12/2/2015#`  no conversion, no formatting.

Comment: @Plutonix True, I had forgotten that VB had date literals.